# SQL select with join are returning double results

Tags: sql, inner-join, redundancy

I am trying to select some data from different tables using join.

First, here is my SQL (MS) query:

```
SELECT Polls.pollID, 
       Members.membername, 
       Polls.polltitle, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PollChoices WHERE pollID=Polls.pollID) AS 'choices',
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PollVotes WHERE PollVotes.pollChoiceID = PollChoices.pollChoicesID) AS 'votes'
FROM Polls
INNER JOIN Members
ON Polls.memberID = Members.memberID
INNER JOIN PollChoices
ON PollChoices.pollID = Polls.pollID;
```

And the tables involved in this query is here:
[image: tables]

The query returns this result:

```
pollID   | membername | polltitle | choices | votes
---------+------------+-----------+---------+-------
10000036 | TestName   | Test Title|   2     |   0
10000036 | TestName   | Test Title|   2     |   1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having? You show data definitions, but you don't show any input data. If we don't know what the input is, we have no idea what output should show up. It looks like the output is correct if we assume that there are multiple input records.

Comment: Can you include the Input records specific to the pollID = 10000036

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your INNER JOIN with `PollChoices` is bringing in more than 1 row for a given `poll` as there are 2 choices for the poll 10000036 as indicated by `choices` column.

You can change the query to use `GROUP BY` and get the counts.

In case you don't have entries for each member in the `PollVotes` or `Polls` table, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT Polls.pollID, 
       Members.membername, 
       Polls.polltitle, 
       COUNT(PollChoices.pollID) as 'choices',
       COUNT(PollVotes.pollvoteId) as 'votes'
FROM Polls
INNER JOIN Members
ON Polls.memberID = Members.memberID
INNER JOIN PollChoices
ON PollChoices.pollID = Polls.pollID
INNER JOIN PollVotes
ON PollVotes.pollChoiceID = PollChoices.pollChoicesID
AND PollVotes.memberID = Members.memberID
GROUP BY Polls.pollID, 
         Members.membername, 
         Polls.polltitle
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your easy understandable explanation and solution :) +1 and accept

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 1 row for each PollChoices record since there are multiple choices per Polls INNER JOIN Members. You may be expecting the SELECT COUNT(*) sub-queries to act as a GROUP BY clause, but they don't.

If that doesn't make sense, add a bare minimum of sample data and the expected result and we can help more.

Answer (score 1):

This query result is telling you the number of votes **per choice** in each poll.

In your example, this voter named TestName answered the poll (with ID 10000036) and gave one choice 1 vote, and the second choice 0 votes.  This is why you are getting two rows in your result.

I'm not sure if you are expecting just one row because you didn't specify what data, exactly, you are trying to select.  However if you are trying to see the number of votes that TestName has submitted, for each choice where the vote was greater than 1, then you will have to modify your query like this:

```
select * from
(SELECT Polls.pollID, 
           Members.membername, 
           Polls.polltitle, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PollChoices WHERE pollID=Polls.pollID) AS 'choices',
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PollVotes WHERE PollVotes.pollChoiceID = PollChoices.pollChoicesID) AS 'votes'
    FROM Polls
    INNER JOIN Members
    ON Polls.memberID = Members.memberID
    INNER JOIN PollChoices
    ON PollChoices.pollID = Polls.pollID) as mysubquery where votes <> 0;
```